# Jquery or javascript regex to extract decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex-group

I need to write a regex in javascript or jquery  to extract all decimals with this format "XXXXXX,XX".

My string to analyse is :

```
aaawhatyouwant"4666","bla bla","5,00","27/06/2022","09:00","14:00","","0x7fffffffffffffff","4670","0,50","28/06/2022","07:00","07:30","4669","08:00","08:30"whatyouwantbbb
```

And my regex is:

```
/aaa.*(?:(?:"(\d+,\d\d)").+)bbb/g
```

So expected results would be:

```
5,00 is missing!
0,50 ok
```

Any help would be appreciated!:)

Regards
François

Comment: [RegExr](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: `.,` in a regular expression means any character followed by a comma. you probably don't need the `.` if all your numbers are going to use a comma as the decimal separator.

Comment: Thanks Phuzi! Right, my regex should be  aaa.*(?:(?:"(\d+,\d\d)")*.+)bbb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match only comma separated decimal numbers try this:

```
/(\d+,\d+)/g
```

You can test it here: https://regexr.com/6oop4

To match comma and period separated numbers try this:

```
(\d+(,|\.)\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with this regex expression :

```
/(?:(?:"(\d+,\d\d)"))/g
```

I get my 2 results 5,00 and 0,50 now. Great!

But when I add fixed start and end, I get only one result...

```
/aaawhatyouwant.*(?:(?:"(\d+,\d\d)").*)+.*whatyouwantbbb/g
```

Any suggestion ?